# Übersetzung von "to tell (infer) something by something"

Tags: translation

Wie kann *tell (infer) sth. by sth.* am besten übersetzt werden?
Also, wenn ich recht habe, wird *You can tell by looking at him that he is a smoker* als *Man sieht ihm an, dass er ein Raucher ist* übersetzt.
Wie ist es mit beispielsweise *You can tell by the color of the indicator that ...*?

Ich bin auf Sätze mit *an etw. merken* und *aus etw. schließen* gestoßen, wenn ich im Internet nachgeguckt habe. 
Wie kommt es in der Umgangssprache vor? Und was für eine Konstruktion wird am häufigsten gebraucht?

Comment: Beide Vorschläge sind im allgemeinen möglich, und im besonderen kommt es drauf an ;-) Was genau willst Du nun wissen? Eine Übersetzung für den Beispielsatz? Weitere Varianten? Allgemeine Regeln zur Auswahl zwischen den Varianten?

Comment: Ich gebe zu,dass ich mich da nicht deutlich genug ausgedrückt habe. 
Ich wollte halt wissen, welche der Varianten würde ein muttersprachlicher in der alltäglichen Sprache bevorzugen.
Wie du erwähnst hast, "Allgemeine Regeln zur Auswahl zwischen den Varianten"

Comment: "Man sieht an der Farbe des Indikators, dass..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch verwende ich die Variante *an etw. merken*.

```
Ich merke an deinen Augen, dass du betrunken bist.
```

Wenn etwas beschrieben wird, wird eher *aus etw. schließen* verwendet.

```
Aus der Farbe des Indikators lässt sich schließen, dass...
```

Sprachlich wiederum in diesem Beispiel:

```
Die Farbe des Indikators zeigt an, dass...
```

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, am häufigsten wird "erkennen" benützt. "An der Farbe des Indikators erkennt man ...".